# c# Parse Long Date string to date time

Tags: c#, string, datetime

I want to parse long date string to date.

```
//Friday, December 19, 201421:00:44:987
```

Here's what Ive done so far

```
DateTime.ParseExact(item.Date, "dddd, MMMM d, yyyyhh:mm:SS:fff", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).ToShortDateString();
```

Gives the exception `String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.`

Comment: ...how is it going, so far?

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.

Comment: The problem is I guess in my data, the year and hours are mixed up :(

Comment: `DateTime theDate = DateTime.ParseExact("2014-12-19:00:44:987", "yyyy-MM-dd:mm:ss:fff", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);` works as well

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `Friday, December 19, 201421:00:44:987`represents Date in the ***Day of the week, Month Day, YearHour:Minute:Second:Milliseconds***  format.

When looking to your format I can see **two** mistakes. First, the hour in your stirng is 21. And it is using a 24-hour clock from 0 to 23. So, you must change `hh` to `HH`. And the second mistake is that you have used  `SS` to specify Seconds in your string. You must change `SS` to `ss`:

```
DateTime.ParseExact(item.Date, "dddd, MMMM d, yyyyHH:mm:ss:fff", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).ToShortDateString();
```

[.NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/LxZE8X)

Look at the table in [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) article which describes all custom date and time format specifiers.

Comment: Still getting the same error. Did u try before answering ?

Comment: @user3549519 Yes, definitely.

Comment: @user3549519 Have you changed `SS` to `ss` also?

Comment: yes... copied your code. Still getting the same error. This is really a hard one.

Comment: @user3549519 :) Nice. I am glad.

Answer (score 0):

or try to it

```
DateTime date = new DateTime(2015, 01, 02, 9, 23, 18, DateTimeKind.Utc);
```